# after encrypt, update of custom configuration in web.config not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="ServerName" value="localhost" />
    <add key="DatabaseName" value="amc_live" />    
    <!--<add key="PwdName" value="123456" />-->
    <add key="LogError" value="1" />
  </appSettings>


  <secureAppSettings>
    <add key="UserName" value="root" />
    <add key="Password" value="12345" />
  </secureAppSettings>
```

here in the above code... after encrypt of securityAppSetting i cant able to update that programatically .

i use below code to update

```
xmlDoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//secureAppSettings/add[@key='Password']").Attributes["value"].Value = Pass;
xmlDoc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("secureAppSettings");
```

but in below line of code  it is throwing error like  "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when i try to update.

```
xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//secureAppSettings/add[@key='Passw‌​ord']").Attributes["‌​value"].Value = Pass;
```

Thanks.

Comment: please include all information you have about error messages/exceptions that occur, "not working" and "unable to" is too vague.

Comment: xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//secureAppSettings/add[@key='Password']").Attributes["value"].Value = Pass;                                                                                 for the above line it is showing  "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error

Comment: @user8878681 Please edit this into your question for clarity, thanks!

Comment: Please ensure the xml file, after encryption, has the right nodes and attributes present.